# Como se chama este recurso do C#

Tags: c#

Eu sempre via isto no c#

```
var button = new Button(this.ApplicationContext);
button.Text = "New button;
```

Só que agora vi que da forma abaixo também da, acessando as propriedades diretamente com `{`, como se chama este recurso?

```
var button = new Button(this.ApplicationContext)
 {
      Text = "New button"
 };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isto é um [inicializador de objeto](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers). Na prática, o que o C# faz é transformar a segunda forma na primeira ao compilar seu código.

Veja que isso não é a mesma coisa que um construtor. Este código é executado *depois* da construção do objeto `Button`, do seu exemplo.